# Redirect to same page with errors

Tags: django

I have a base.html which has a login section at the top of every page.

If the user login fails on any page, I want to be able to redirect to that same page but to render the page with an error message to let the user know what went wrong.

I can see I can pass data back if I use render_to_response - then this data (login failed) can be checked in the template and, if set, used to show the error.

But since I want to redirect to whichever page the user was on in the first place, I can't use render_to_response as it doesn't know which template to render - so I have to use the redirect method. But with redirect, I can't pass the error back to the template!

Any ideas on how I should go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what [the messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/) is for.